# WPF DataTemplate and Binding - Is this possible in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, binding

I am DataTemplating a listbox's `ItemSource` to display a series of comboboxes. I want to give the `DisplayMemberPath` of the combo to a property, which is in a different source than its own `ItemsSource`. (Assuming `DisplayMemberPath` is just a string representing name of a property, I am getting this from the user). I have achieved this with a `CollectionViewSource`, but all the comboboxes are displaying the same list.

What I am expecting to have after data templating is to have comboboxes display,

```
ComboboxInstance1.DisplayMemberPath =  PropertyMapOfEmployee in FilterControls[0]
ComboboxInstance2.DisplayMemberPath =  PropertyMapOfEmployee in FilterControls[1]
```

Is this possible to achieve in XAML ?

Thanks. Mani

UserControl:

```
<Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="bindingSource" Source="{Binding BindingItems}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="FilterSource" Source="{Binding FilterControls}"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CustomTypes:FilterElement}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindingEmp}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Source={StaticResource FilterSource}, 
                                            Path=PropertyMapofEmployee}" />
    </DataTemplate>

<Resources>

 ---

<DockPanel>
     <ListBox x:Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterControls}" />
 </DockPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
List<FilterElement> FilterControls;
List<Employee> Employees

class FilterElement 
{
    string Caption;
    String PropertyMapofEmployee
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindingEmp}"
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding PropertyMapofEmployee}" />
```

Comment: I don't think PropertyMapOfEmployee is a property on the Employee class so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Thanks .. this actually fixes both the original and current issue.

Comment: It works because PropertyMapOfEmployee is  a proprty of FilterControls which is binded to thge ListBox (which is datatemplated).Hence the combo bindings always refers to the parent, unless specifically set using 'Source=' in the binding. Hence it works.

Comment: @Dave, the Employee object is not the DataContext of the ComboBox, it's the DataContext of the ComboBoxItem...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that in XAML. (Having the DisplayMemberPath point to a property that is on an object other than the DataContext). You may want to look at the [RelativeSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) to see if that would meet your needs.

Have you thought about providing a reference in your Employee object to the FilterElement and then hooking up to the binding the Employee.PropertyMapOfEmployee property that you've created?